# Бесплатная CMS, в которой возможна работа с 1С

Tags: 1с, cms, база-данных

Здравствуйте, посоветуйте мне пожалуйста бесплатную CMS которую можно связать с БД 1С, Заранее благодарю

Comment: Бред......

Comment: >Бред......

@Андрей-Аршинов, обоснуйте.

Comment: Может быть будет полезно: [Как интегрировать 1С с интернет-магазином?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/122096/как-интегрировать-1с-с-интернет-магазином)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любую можно. Берете протокол 1ски и связываете. Можно из битрикса выдрать, он там точно есть и неглубоко зарыт.

Еще для многих популярных есть разной кривизны плагины. Не советую их использовать, не разобравшись.

Comment: А что за протокол? Подробнее можете рассказать?

Comment: http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/131/

Comment: Вы сами то пробовали? Хотя бы прочитать описание "протокола Битрикса". Это излишнее усложнение, годящиеся только для коробочных продуктов, на разработку которых можно потратить кучу времени, чтобы потом продавать сотнями. Для конкретной индивидуальной задачи столь сложная вещь не целесообразна.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для выгрузки CommerceXML, а потом его подгружаете и обрабатываете с помощью любой CMS. Есть готовые решения для Drupal.
Должны выгрузиться 2 файла:

1. import.xml - содержит информацию о
       товарах и его свойствах. Может
       содержать, например, вес товара, его
       цвет и пр.
2. export.xml - содержит
       информацию о ценах на товар. Может
       быть несколько типов цен. Здесь же
       содержится информация о количестве
       товара на складе.
3. В зависимости от
       настроек 1С может быть либо архив
       или папка с изображениями.

Comment: По подробнее можно? Мне нужно сделать интернет магазин который будет соединяться с 1С, решения типа Bitrix дорогие, а я еврей :)

Comment: Что конкретно поподробнее? XML файлы обрабатываются с помощью php очень легко. Структура XML будет понятна при просмотре файлов выгрузки из 1С.

Comment: Может решения и есть. Но они, мягко говоря, условно-рабочие. Для маленького магазина пойдет. Но вот для 5000-8000 наименований товаров пришлось реализовывать свой механизм. Полностью с нуля как в 1С так и на сайте. Но доволен - скорость загрузки выросла неимоверно. Все перепробованные коробочные решения слишком грузят веб-сервер, слишком долго выполняются. Это нормально, это следствие универсальности. Но - если уж программировать, то программировать под конкретную задачу заточенное решение.

Comment: 40k товаров заливается в базу очень быстро, если делать load inline через Mysql из обычного файла типа csv, выгруженного из 1с  
Вообще полное обновление магазина с регионалными ценами и ок 40к товаров и кучей категорий занимало примерно 1-2 минуты.

Comment: Вот-вот. Прямое заливание в базу данных. А все эти "протоколы Битрикс" - весчь универсальная и, закономерно, тормозная. А еще и картинки...